# LinkedHashSet appears to be leaving a duplicate element

Tags: java

I am curious if anyone knows why the first element in my LinkHashSet seems to be allowing duplicates? I am doing a code challenge from CodeEval and when I input values 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6 the output from my program displays 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 It's only the first element that is causing the problem.

I am using jre 1.8.0_45. I got tired of troubleshooting the issue and checked in the challenge and the website accepted my solution, so I am wondering if there is a bug in my version of Java. I searched and have seen no other posts of anyone having issues with LinkHashSet producing duplicates.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class UniqueElements 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner  s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = s.nextLine();

        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(line.trim().split(","));

        Set<String> string = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);

        Iterator<String> iter = string.iterator();

         while (true) 
         {
             System.out.print(iter.next());

             if (iter.hasNext()) {
                 System.out.print(",");
             } else {
                 System.out.println();
                 break;
             }
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to reproduce, despite the bizarre loop.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(line.trim().split(","))` : Your logic here is wrong. `trim()` only removes leading and trailing spaces from the whole line, not from the individual numbers. So your set contains both the strings `2` and `<space>2` which are two unique elements.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(line.trim().split(","));
```

It creates a list where the first element is `"2"` and the second is `" 2"` (note the leading space).

You need to remove the spaces from the input or split on `", "` or `"\\s*,\\s*"` to allow for spaces before and after the commas.

Comment: Thanks, adding "\\s*,\\s*" to the split fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've wisely used the `trim()` method, but you're not getting all the whitespace from between the list entries. Did you notice that your output list has spaces between the numbers, but your output `println` doesn't insert any?

The first "2" has no leading whitespace. The second " 2" has a leading space. That makes them different `Strings`. Get rid of the space, get rid of the problem.

Using a different regular expression on your `split()` would help. How about `.split(",\\s*")`?

Another option: why are you using `String` values in the first place? If they are all numeric and guaranteed to be so (and the challenge would state that), then converting to `Number` (or even `Integer`, if that's the guarantee) would make the extraneous spaces irrelevant.